# How to upload a file to a specific folder in struts 2

Tags: java, struts2

I want to upload a file from a struts action. I need in that action the path for my folder:

I tried using

```
String contextPath = request.getContextPath();
```

but I'm getting `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: Do you want to download a file?

Comment: No , i want to upload it to a specific folder in WebContent

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

Either store in Catalina which is parent folder to your project folder

```
      String rootPath = System.getProperty("catalina.home");
      File dir = new File(rootPath + File.separator + "yourfolderName");
      if (!dir.exists())
          dir.mkdirs();

      // Create the file on server
      java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
      String Path = dir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + (new Timestamp(date.getTime())).toString().replace(":", "").toString().replace(".", ".").toString().replace(" ","").toString().replace("-","").toString()+".pdf";
```

Or make a folder in your project and store there.

```
if (!file.isEmpty()) {
    //filter for checking file extewnsion
    if(file.getContentType().equalsIgnoreCase("image/jpg") || file.getContentType().equalsIgnoreCase("image/jpeg")){
        //if file is >2 MB or < 2MB
        double size = file.getSize();
        double kilobytes = (size / 1024);
        double megabytes = (kilobytes / 1024);
        if(megabytes<2){
    try {
        byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
        String filePath = request.getRealPath("/")+"yourFolderName\\ProfileImages\\"+SessionManagement.getUserName()+".jpg";
        BufferedOutputStream stream =
                new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath)));
        stream.write(bytes);
        stream.close();

        //console call
    }
    else{
        model.put("error", "Please select File less than 2 MB");
        return new ModelAndView("uploadPhotoTile");
    }
    }else{
        model.put("error", "Please select JPEG File");
        return new ModelAndView("uploadPhotoTile");
    }
} else {
    model.put("error", "Please select File");
    return new ModelAndView("uploadPhotoTile");
}
```